# How do I do a manual Binding instead of the shorthand in Emberjs

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

I am trying to do an attributeBinding for a data attribute.

Here is a starting fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/43/ it is not bound but just takes the value of the string `'App.DateView.endDateString'`.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.CalendarController= Em.Controller.extend();
App.CalendarView = Em.View.extend({
   templateName: 'calendar',
   attributeBindings: ['data-date'],
   'data-date': 'App.DateView.endDateString',  
});

App.DateView = Em.View.extend({
    endDateString: '7/7/2012' /* This actually is a function */
});
```

I want to bind `'data-date'` to `'App.DateView.endDateString'`

I tried using

```
'data-date' : function(){
            Em.Binding('App.CalendarView["data-date"]','App.DateView.endDateString');
            return '1/1/1988';
            }.property().cacheable(),
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `App.DateView` is a View instance, i.e,

```
App.DateView = Em.View.create({ // notice that create() is called
    endDateString : '7/7/2012' 
});
```

the following should work:

```
'data-dateBinding' : 'App.DateView.endDateString',
```

Alternatively you can use (but really no need to):

```
'data-date': function(){
    return App.DateView.get('endDateString');
}.property('App.DateView.endDateString')
```

Comment: you got my big error ie binding to a View class instead of an instance, that just doesnt work. I tried all these but didnt work, the reason was that i was binding to an clacc instance :) Thank you for pointing that out, marking yours as aswer for that extra bit of info.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind a property to a path you have to append `Binding` to the property name, so it's `'data-dateBinding': 'path.to.date'`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/tV2Zq/:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({
    dateString: '7/7/2012'
});

App.CalendarView = Em.View.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['data-date'],
    'data-dateBinding': 'App.dateString'
});​
```

Comment: I got confused when I had to use a string as key instead of usual identifier type (dataDateBinding) , and again i tried this('data-dateBinding') with a DateView class(extend) instead of an instance(cerate) so didnt work :). Let me chack how I can solve this

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like

```
'data-date' : function(){
        return App.get('router').get('dateController').get('endDate');
        }.property('App.router.dateConroller.endDateString','App.router.currentState.name').cacheable(),
```

No idea if there is a better solutions to my problem

Comment: @Zack any thoughts of a better solution if both are classes and not instances, a simple example would be binding view to a controller in an App using Routes and templates. In such a case both view and controller are classes, the objects are instantiated by router logic.